# Disable outlook security settings using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to auto email a report from access using VBA in a macro. The report is sent from Access2007 by outlook2007. When the report is being sent, I get a security message from outlook saying "a program is trying to access your Address book or Contacts" or "a program is trying to access e-mail addresses you have stored in Outlook..." . This message is a problematic for me because I want to use windows task scheduler to automatically send the report without any human interaction.So I want to disable this security notification. I searched on Google and here is the code I have so far but giving me errors and I am not sure what else I should do. Thanks for your help in advance. I am a beginner programmer. The error is

```
Public Sub Send_Report()
Dim strRecipient As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMessageBody As String
Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

OlSecurityManager.ConnectTo outlookapp   'error is here says object required

OlSecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = True
On Error GoTo Finally

strRecipient = "example@yahoo.com"
strSubject = "Tile of report"
strMessageBody = "Here is the message."

DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Report_Name", acFormatPDF, strRecipient, , ,        strSubject, strMessageBody, False

Finally:
OlSecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `OlSecurityManager` is nothing. You haven't declared it, you haven't set it to anything, so when you attempt to use it, VBA has no idea what you're talking about!

It looks like you're trying to use Outlook Security Manager, which is an add-in sold [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/?mapilab). Have you purchased it? Because if not, then you probably don't have it on your system.

If you do have it, then you probably need to declare and set it like this:

```
Dim OlSecurityManager As AddinExpress.Outlook.SecurityManager
Set OlSecurityManager = New AddinExpress.Outlook.SecurityManager
```

If you, as I suspect, don't have it, then an alternative is sending e-mail using CDO. Here's an example:

First, set a reference to the CDO library in Tools > References > checkmark next to *Microsoft CDO for Windows Library* or something like that.

```
Dim cdoConfig
Dim msgOne

Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25 'your port number, usually is 25
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "yourSMTPserver.com" 
    '.Item(cdoSendUserName) = "your username if required"
    '.Item(cdoSendPassword) = "your password if required"
    .Update
End With

Set msgOne = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With msgOne
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
    .To = "recipient@somehwere.com"
    .from = "you@here.com"
    .subject = "Testing CDO"
    .TextBody = "It works just fine."
    .Attachments.Add "C:\myfile.pdf"
    .Send
End With
```

This is a bit more annoying than Outlook, because you need to know in advance the address of the SMTP server to be used.

Comment: You are right! I don't have the outlook security manager add-in. I will use your second method and update you what I get.

Comment: Hi Jean, I don't see the argument for attaching the report from access as PDF in your second code. does it allow sending attachment as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Jean for your quick reply! Actually the attachment is a report residing in Access database. It is not attaching a file from the local drive. To make it more clear, I have a database in Access it has a report on it. I am trying to auto email this report directly from Access and sent it out as attachment. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please post this as a new question. The subject of the current question is "Disable outlook security settings using VBA".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I just ran into a similar problem. There is another solution using `Outlook.Application`!

I stumble upon it while looking for the solution, full credit here: 
http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4334

But what this site's solution simply suggest, instead of using the `.send` command, use the `.Display" command and then send some keys from the keyboard to send the email, like below:

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "Someone@Somewhere.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is an automated email!"
        .Body = "Howdy there! Here, have an automated mail!"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Display 'Display instead of .send
        SendKeys "%{s}", True 'send the email without prompts
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End
End Sub
```